# find peers on wifi network ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to search for other devices logged into a wifi network that are hosting the application on a specific port.

How can I detect the presence of these other devices without knowing their address or even necessarily the port they are hosting on?

Once discovered, I should be able to contact the device and establish a connection with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most standard "iOS way" would be to use [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) to announce and listen for announcements for the application.

Comment: I want to connect to a camera which is on same wifi network as iOS device. Can I do this using Bonjour

Comment: @IronMan What model camera? Some announce themselves over Bonjour, some use proprietary protocols.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
As of iOS7 GKSession is deprecated..

Why don't you use a GameKit Session
[Apple GKSession Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A GKSession object provides the ability to discover and connect to nearby iOS devices using Bluetooth or Wi-fi.

Just because it's called GameKit, doesn't mean it can only be used in games :)