# Is it possible to make one iPhone discover other devices on the same local network?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, ipad, networking

Let's say you have five devices on the same local network. Is it possible for iOS device 1 to act as a central hub and "discover" the other four devices on the same network and communicate with them, almost acting like a server. Do we just need to find some unused port and communicate over it? Is this possible from a HTML5 web app, or would a native app be required?

Comment: This post is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17361977/2035473

Answer (score 0):

I never done it with ios device.
but if your point is to "discover" or scanning network using web app..then it is possible.
I've done a multi tier web app which has a server that has to scan a local network to find it's child just by using php. There are many parameter that you can use to determine the discovered device is your target or not.

Comment: does the server scan the local network or does the device scan the local network? we need the device to scan the local network.

Comment: Unfortunately the server does the scanning, because I wanted to push information to client's device.

But I've seen some app in android that can do local scanning (ex: Fing) which is preety light. If android can do it, I'm sure iOs can do that as well. Maybe you can try to download Fing .apk can see how it works.